# control python code to run on different core

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have ubuntu OS on my machine that has 4 cores. Also, I have a python script called python.py that has different functions such as def1, def2, and def 3.
I would like to run def1 on core 1 , and the rest on core 2 to 4.
I know that I can use:

```
       #taskset -c 1 python.py
```

The problem with this makes the whole script run on one core for each function inside it. however, I want to run specific function on specific core such as:

```
       def add(a,b):
           return a+b

       def sub(s, t):
           return s-t

       def mult(y,x):
           return y*x

      add(3,4)  # run this function on core 0
      sub(3,4)  # run this function on core 1
      mult(2,3)  # I don't core run on core 2 or 3
```

My question is: Is This Possible?

Comment: I think you have partially answered your own question. You can use `subprocess` module and pass `taskset` with the necessary arguments. You would have to reorganize your code such that each function is in its own script and such that you can consume the results.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can run each function in a different process in order to take advantage of multiple cores. Here is an example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def add(a,b):
    return a+b

def sub(s, t):
    return s-t

def mult(y,x):
    return y*x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # construct a different process for each function
    processes = [Process(target=add, args=(3,4)),
                 Process(target=sub, args=(3,4)),
                 Process(target=mult, args=(2,3))]

    # kick them off 
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    # now wait for them to finish
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

There is no need to force the OS to run a specific process on a specific core. If you have multiple cores on your CPU the OS is going to be scheduling the processes across those cores. It is unlikely that you need to do any sort of CPU [pinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) here.

The above example is too simple to see your multiple cores get engaged. Instead you can try this example which is a simple CPU bound problem variation of the above -- i.e. it is just a version that requires more computation.

```
from multiprocessing import Process


def add(a, b):
    total = 0
    for a1, b1 in zip(a, b):
        total = a1 + b1
    return total


def sub(s, t):
    total = 0
    for a1, b1 in zip(s, t):
        total = a1 - b1
    return total


def mult(y, x):
    total = 0
    for a1, b1 in zip(y, x):
        total = a1 * b1
    return total


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # construct a different process for each function
    max_size = 1000000000
    processes = [Process(target=add, args=(range(1, max_size), range(1, max_size))),
                 Process(target=sub, args=(range(1, max_size), range(1, max_size))),
                 Process(target=mult, args=(range(1, max_size), range(1, max_size)))]

    # kick them off 
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    # now wait for them to finish
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

If you look at your `top` output (and press `1` to see the cores) you should see something like this where the three cores are being used at 100% (or close to it). That's without needing to do any CPU pinning. It is easier to trust in the OS to get the parallelism done.

[image]

Comment: Thanks paul, But How I am sure they run on different cores if I am not telling the process on which core has to run.

Comment: You don't need to tell the OS to run them on different cores. When you have multiple cores and multiple processes then the OS is going to use those cores.

Comment: Thank Paul. But I think I should have a way  to tell the OS to run them on different cores. because there two functions I don't them to run on the same core.  If I let the OS scheduling the processes across those cores, I can't  grantee whether they run on the same core or not

Comment: I have a similar problem and have 3 processes that basically need to run forever (or at least a year, i.e. that shouldn't run one after another) and am wondering how to make sure they "truly" run in parallel (some I/O bound operations need next to zero execution delay). Not sure if I'm on the right path...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I came here looking if it's possible to force an specific core to execute code. The question does indeed ask what I'm looking for:  `I would like to run def1 on core 1 , and the rest on core 2 to 4`  However this answer doesn't answer that question at all, it just says "There is no need to force the OS to run a specific process on a specific core[...] It is unlikely that you need to do any sort of CPU pinning here".